# How to submit wp favorite posts plugin using Ajax?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, favorites

I'm using WP Favorite Posts plugin to add posts like favorite posts, and it wokr perfectly uisng this code `<?php wpfp_link(); ?>` but when I click on add to favorite button it reload all page. How I can do that using ajax to not reload page.

Answer (score 0):

With no code it's hard to solve the exact problem. However, including a

```
return false;
```

Into the Javascript function that is called when your button is clicked, should prevent it from reloading the page.